# install GNOME in CentOS 6.4 KVM

Tags: linux, gnome, centos6

i have a dedicated server with Linux CentOS 6.4 KVM,
 it does support visualization, i would like to know how can i install GNOME (desktop) to it, can someone post every step? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to read [that](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Unix/Linux/LINUX_AddGNOMEToCentOSMinimalInstall.shtml) which describe the all point.

- Re-install CentOs
- Install Desktop Packages (reboot between each step) :

> > yum -y groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" "Fonts"
> >
> > yum -y groupinstall "Graphical Administration Tools"
> >
> > yum -y groupinstall "Internet Browser"
> >
> > yum -y groupinstall "General Purpose Desktop"
> >
> > yum -y groupinstall "Office Suite and Productivity"
> >
> > yum -y groupinstall "Graphics Creation Tools"

- Don't change `/etc/inittab`

Comment: I made this yesterday also, and had to format my dedicated server,

Comment: is there any way i can contact you so you can help me? please? thanks :)

Comment: where, in the last step, it would not start, how, i edit the /etc/inittab.

id:5:initdefault: 
why, i dont really know,

Comment: Alright, one question, where do I type startx? how do i log in GNOME? i have only SSH access and IPMI Terminal to the dedicated server,

Comment: so, when i edit everything, and all is installed, what is next? how do i log in "Console Mode", thanks :)

Comment: it keeps giving me warnings:
** (gnome-settings-daemon:2058): WARNING **: Connection failed, reconnecting...

** (gnome-settings-daemon:2058): WARNING **: Connection failed, reconnecting...

** (gnome-settings-daemon:2

Comment: when i type Startx, sorry, i am pretty new to linux,

Comment: See the edit and tell me, I'll remove all the comments to avoid extra space used

Comment: Alright, i just finish reinstalling CentOS, i am installing 
yum -y groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" "Fonts" right now, i will restart after this and install the other packages. Thank you

Comment: Hello, got a problem, http://i.imgur.com/zYVUTiH.png there is an image, can we talk in an instant messenger so you can help me? thanks.

Comment: When does this occurs? We cant move to SO chat because you not have enough rep. And I can't move to a public chat due to my network policy